# Add a gradient to a line in OpenLayers3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

thanks for taking the time to read.

I have been tasked with drawing a LineString as a series of differently styled segments, ideally represented as various gradients.

Not running into any problem getting them to show up, just getting them to render as a gradient. For the layer's style function, I create a new style array and return it with the style I'd like in it.

If I just use a style with a stroke, everything renders great. When I add a fill (even a simple fill with a single color) the fill doesn't show up.

I have a lot of latitude and freedom here, so if using a LineString is the wrong approach, I am happy to go a different direction.

Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but I would think that a fill wouldn't work with a lineString. To get each segement to display in a different color, I would add a property to the feature that can be interpreted by the style function where you can adjust the color..If you need fill then try polygon map layer.

Comment: You can use the style's `geometryFunction` to render individual line segments differently. For each segment, you'll need one style. The `geometryFunction` returns a different line segment for each style.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a fill, asign an array of stroke styles to your lines. One for the inner (fill) and one for the outer (stroke).
Like this:

```
  var styles = [
                new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({

                        color: "#000000",
                        width: 10
                    })

                }),
                new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({

                        color: "#ff0000",
                        width: 6
                    })
                })
  ];
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/oygbL4yx/) to see the effect ( just draw a line on your map)